# I need one jQuery effect

Tags: jquery

I had many photos, each photo size is 200x150px,each line has four photos,there have 4 lines. When I click one of them, the photo will fadeout with some introduce text, the original array photos will move to the both side of the page.(there should be have a animate action) When I close the fadeout photo, the original photos will move back to their first position.

Does anyone have a demo for this sort of effect? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "array photos will move to the both side of the page"?

Comment: I think you should storyboard your desired animation to help to explain.

Comment: What's an "effection"? Methinks you mean "effect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to have two actions -

1.fadein one photo and simultaenously slide the other photos to side.

1. And then fadeout the centered photo and slide the other photos to original place.

There may be plugins (may be jquery plugins) available for the entire thing. You may search. But you may also try breaking the actions into fading and sliding and try out this:-

For the fading action jquery's [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) should work. For sliding action, I am not sure which one to use, but from the list of [jquery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) may be near to what you want.

Demos are given in those pages